# Concurrent struts action calls on the same method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, struts2

I'm using struts2 and spring integrated framework, hibernate and Postgres SQL in my project. During performance testing there is an issue when more than 2 users are trying to insert the same entity(different instances) at the same time. The following error is thrown :

> 11:24:18,598 ERROR [stderr] (http--172.20.211.210-8080-1)
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Flush
>   during cascade is dangerous; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous

Or,the entity gets added but is incompletely added. 
I'm not sure how exactly the transactions are being handled. Please do guide for some input on the same

Comment: @Adi: please don't use inline code spans (`like this`) to highlight stuff that isn't code, they are only meant for code within sentences. Also make sure to fix all the issues in a post you can find. For more information, see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135113/220428). Thanks!

Comment: @Quntas 94 Heavy - Ok. will keep in mind.

Comment: Not sure what answers are you looking for. Probably you need to fetch entities before persisting and use versions.

Comment: If you need to learn transactions you might read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21024637/573032).

Comment: I just need multiple users to access the same action at the same time without the transactions being interrupted